# Joomla 3.6 - Additional languages not showing in language switcher when logged off

Tags: joomla, permissions, multilingual, joomla3.5

I have a webpage with 3 languages.

The multi languages status shows all is fine.
When I am logged into the front end as superuser the language switcher works like a charm.

But when I log off and visit the page as public, the language switcher works only in a menue where I have a JSN UniForm for all languages if I unpublish it, the language switcher does not work either.
But I cannot see a difference in the settings.

I can access the correct language by changing the url to the specific language and the correct pages are displayed.

We are using Joomla 3.6.4, and the template JSN Air Pro.

---

Update:
I realized I did not describe the problem correctly:
When I am on the English page the language switcher is shown, but it does not show the other languages. So ti is not possible to change the language via the language switcher.
All three languages are installed and published.

---

Do you have any suggestions what setting I need to change?

Comment: Quick update, the developer had to fix a setting. It appears to be a problem with the framework. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

[image]Go to your module (Language Switcher) set Access -> public, now you can see module in front end as a public.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I realized that I did not clearly described the problem, as only one language is shown in public and you cannot change the langeuage. I edited the question. The language switcher is on public and published.